# Return a python varargs type

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to return a varargs type and also specify it in the function type for a very simple function. The code written so far is the following:

```
def dRange(start: int, endIncluded: int):
    retrievedRange: list[int] = list(range(start, endIncluded + 1))
    return *retrievedRange # Unpack operation not allowed in this context (Pylance)
```

How can I set the type to be varargs?

The final use of the function is to create such structures:

```
[
    155,
    153,
    150,
    148,
    dRange(146, 142),
    113,
    112,
    110,
]
```

Comment: [edit] your post and add how do you want your method to be called and results to re retrieved

Comment: "varargs type" there is no varargs type. You can return a *container*, like a list, tuple, dict etc but the caller must do the unpacking.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do in the method, for the results to be able to be unpacked, just return a structure that can be unpacked, like `list` or `tuple`

```
def dRange(start: int, endIncluded: int):
    retrievedRange: list[int] = list(range(start, endIncluded + 1))
    return retrievedRange


print(dRange(1, 10))  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

a, b, *_ = dRange(1, 2)
print(a, b)  # 1 2

a, *_, b = dRange(1, 10)
print(a, b)  # 1 10

a, b, c, *_, d, e = dRange(1, 10)
print(a, b, c, d, e)  # 1 2 3 9 10
```